# How to include a html element in cakephp 3.2 anchor tag?

Tags: php, html, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

Here i want to include a html element  in cakephp 3.2 anchor link.
I have tried it ,but its not working.Below is code.

```html
  <?= $this->Html->link(__('<i class="fa fa-eye"></i>'), ['action' => 'edit', $user->id],['class'=>"btn btn-primary"]) ?>
```

I want below html in cake format.

```html
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="/adminCake3/adminCake3/users/edit/3"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
```

Here inplace of icon ,html tag() is coming.Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: what it the current ouput of your code?

Comment: I have added  a screenshorts please check it. @jameshwartlopez lopez

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> HTML special characters in $title will be converted to HTML entities.
>   To disable this conversion, set the escape option to false in the
>   $options array.
>
> Setting escape to false will also disable escaping of attributes of
>   the link.

Try this

```
echo $this->Html->link(
        $this->Html->tag('i','',array('class'=>'fa fa-eye')),
        '/adminCake3/adminCake3/users/edit/'.$user->id,
        ['escape' => false,'class' => 'btn btn-primary']
    );
```

or

```
echo $this->Html->link(
    '<i class="fa fa-eye"></i>',
    '/adminCake3/adminCake3/users/edit/'.$user->id,
    ['escape' => false,'class' => 'btn btn-primary']
);
```

**Visit [Cake's docs](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/html.html#creating-links)**

Comment: can you post the current html output?

Comment: <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/adminCake3/adminCake3/adminCake3/adminCake3/users/edit/3">&lt;i class="fa fa-eye"&gt;&lt;/i&gt;</a>

Comment: Use `'escape'=>false` to disable the escaping :D

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

User This method:

```
<?= $this->Html->link(__('<i class="fa fa-eye"></i>'), ['action' => 'edit', $user->id],['class'=>"btn btn-primary"],['escape'=>false]) ?>
```

Comment: Its not working.<i class="fa fa-eye"></i> is coming in place of icon.

Comment: Try this. It may be help
<?= $this->Html->link('<i class="fa fa-eye"></i>', ['action' => 'edit', $user->id],['class'=>"btn btn-primary"],['escape'=>false]) ?>

Answer (score 0):

Make your anchor link

```
$this->Html->link('<i class="fa fa-eye"></i> Edit', ['action' => 'edit', $user->id],['escape'=>false,'class'=>'btn btn-xs btn-primary']);
```

This is working code.